# How to run commands from powershell file using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Command

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to run the commands from powershell file using `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline` class.

It works when I pass the script directly as string

```
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    runspace.Open();
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);
    
    List<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke().ToArray().ToList();
```

But I am not getting how to run the commands from the powershell file. Basically I want to run the script from the powershell file

I tried to check the methods of `System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Command` class also, but could not find anything useful there.

Could anybody please help?

Comment: Your code is C# code that uses the PowerShell SDK. To run PowerShell code from a file, create a `*.ps1` file with PowerShell code in it. If this doesn't help, please clarify your problem.

Comment: @mklement0 - I exactly want to do that. Currently I pass script to the command as string. I want to put the string in `.ps1` file and call it from there. That I am not able to find how to run through this. How should I pass file path to the script?

Comment: From inside a PowerShell session, just invoke a `*.ps1` file directly, but note that to execute one located in the current directory, you must use `.\ `; e.g. `.\script.ps1`. From outside of PowerShell, use the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh): `pwsh -File .\script.ps1` (PowerShell 7+) / `powershell -File .\script.ps1` (Windows PowerShell).